# Eclipse Failing to build classes

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has red cross for error on the project but there are no more red crosses on any files or anything in the project.

On running "build Project" there are no .class files created.

There does not seem to be any entries in the log file in workspace/.metadata.  In fact, I deleted the log file and a new one has not been created.

I have tried Clean and clean all to no effect.

Any suggestions to look for where there might be a problem with this project ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error message? Check the `Problems` tab in the right bottom view.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the 'problems' view you'll probably find an error message (this is normally displayed at the bottom, but if not go to : window -> show view -> problems.

Generally it's something like a build path error, or a JVM isn't correctly set.

Comment: If you get no satisfaction from the Problems view, I'd also look in the view where Eclipse puts its own errors (not errors in your code, but errors relating to its own execution).  That's the Error Log view, which you can find in the same place as the Problems view, which is via Window -> Show View.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...I had confused the Error log view with the Problem view and had not checked it.  On looking at problem view, I see there is a dependancy problem.